# Where to ask about editing fonts?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation, fonts

I need to ask a question about how to modify an OpenType .otf font to create a subset of the font with limited characters to reduce file size.  Where should I ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this would be off-topic at http://stackoverflow.com. But if those font files can be used with TEX, maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place?

Or maybe [the beta Graphic Design site?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Typesetting isn't really SO's forté.  However, I can't think of a better qualified site.

Comment: Both seem like good options.  I didn't know about Graphic Design, so thanks for letting me know about it.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this old question.

The right place to ask is probably [GraphicDesign.StackExchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).